# Slider Next and Prev button is under the slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the tutorial, this code seem to be working fine, but when implemented in my index.html, the Next and Prev Chevron icons are appearing under the Slider, not on the slider. See attached screenshot, you can see the buttons, small on the bottom left corner. What is the issue here? Any Bootstrap class missing?

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="gallery-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#gallery-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#gallery-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#gallery-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Slider image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slider image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Slider image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption.</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#gallery-carousel" clsas="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#gallery-carousel" clsas="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[Screenshot of slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evZnn.jpg)

Comment: You don't show us the styling which is most likely affecting the positioning

Comment: I haven't attached any external Stylesheet to the page. I have added two styles. in the same page

Comment: "<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
</style>"

There are no external stylesheet. Just the Bootstrap link, jQuery and Bootstrap JS script links are the extrenal links.

Comment: That should be in the question.

Comment: Oops, sorry. So the carousel code is fine? No issues in it?

Comment: Looks like missing CSS. You have either forgotten to put a stylesheet in or if you have, then it's not loading. Look in your console for some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<a href="#gallery-carousel" clsas="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
 </a>
<a href="#gallery-carousel" clsas="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

For:

```
<a href="#gallery-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a href="#gallery-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

The **class** attribute is misspelled

Comment: Thank you. I checked spelling of every class names, not the 'class' itself, my bad :D Anyways, thanks a lot for the help, that fixed it.